# How to use trello webhook callbackURL pointing to localhost in php codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, trello

I have created a web-based system in codeigniter and some trello integration using its API services. I wanted to achieve something like if there is a new card created in a particular board it will also send a notification in my system that a new card is created. I started reading some documentation in trello webhooks but I just can't figure it out. Am I heading in the right way? Would it be valid if I provide a callbackURL pointing in localhost `callbackURL: "localhost/main_controller/trelloCallback"` ? However the code below returns a 400 status. Please help me. Thank you.

**Javascript**

```
$.post("https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/5db4c9fbb5b2kaf8420771072b203616f3874fa92a4c57f0c796cf90819fa05c/webhooks?key=a2a93deccc7064dek5f4011c2e9810d6", {
    description: "My first webhook",
    callbackURL: "localhost/dti_infosys/main_controller/trelloCallback",
    idModel: "5a73c33ad9a2dk1b473612eb",
});
```

**main_controller/trelloCallback**

```
function trelloCallback() {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $action = json_decode($json,true);
    var_dump($action);
}
```

[image]

Comment: `localhost/main_controller/trelloCallback` in this, there should be `localhost/folder_name/controller_name/method_name` in your `callback` URL.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the folder name but still it doesn't work

Comment: Trello’s servers will make a POST request to your callback URL when changes occur. What do you think, can Trello reach _your_ localhost via the internet …?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but this use case of having an external tool access our localhost for development is quite common.

So for anyone (OP included) that would like a cloud based service to be able to call a local endpoint, you can use tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Basically, it sets up a URL accessible via internet that forwards all calls to one of your local ports.

Let's say that your local webserver running your PHP listens on the port 8000 on your machine.

With ngrok installed, you could execute the following command:

```sh
$> ngrok http 8000
```

That would set up the forwarding session:

```sh
ngrok by @inconshreveable

Session Status                online
Session Expires               6 hours, 21 minutes
Version                       2.3.35
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://b5d44737.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000
Forwarding                    https://b5d44737.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000
```

You can then use any of the `Forwarding` addresses pointing to `ngrok.io` to access your local webserver through internet, meaning that if you were to provide an URL using any of these addresses instead of `localhost` to an external tool, it would be able to indirectly call your local endpoint.

In your case, your javascript call to create a Trello webhook would be:

```js
$.post("https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>/webhooks?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>", {
    description: "My first webhook",
    callbackURL: "https://b5d44737.ngrok.io/dti_infosys/main_controller/trelloCallback",
    idModel: "<YOUR_MODEL_ID>",
});
```

**A bit of warning though:** In the case of ngrok, the `Forwarding` URLs are randomized at each session startup, meaning that the webhooks you created on one session would not work an another session because there callbacksUrl wouldn't be valid anymore.
Note that you can subscribe to a paid plan to "reserve" ngrok subdomains and have URL consistency between sessions. Or you could manually update your webhooks callbackUrls with the new forarding URLs.

Anyway, I hope this will help!

P.S.: When the forwarding session runs, you can access `localhost:4040` to inspect calls made on the forwarding URLs and retry some of them.